# Get userinput in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to get user inputs using the  tag in HTML and not the prompt function in JavaScript.

I also don't want to have to use another language on top of this like php.

*Edit*
Something like this would be desirable

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but without using a .asp

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning the basics

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<button onclick="myJsFunction()"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myJsFunction(){
    var text=document.getElementById('input1').value;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works just how I need it to!

Comment: inline javascript is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: I'm using a .js file to store the actual JavaScript, but the code itself works how I need it to.

Answer (score 5):

Create an `input` tag with `id` attribute

```
<input type="text" id="a" name="b" />
```

in javascript, you can get the value of an `input` field via its `id`

```
var x = document.getElementById('a').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

and for textbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Press me</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
         function myFunction()
         {
            var x;
            var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Safa Alrawi");
            if (person!=null)
            {
              x="Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
              }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has three kind of popup boxes: Alert box, Confirm box, and Prompt box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please re-read the question -- the OP wants to use HTML. Secondly, inline javascript is bad practice and should be avoided.